# What's wrong with this code of python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

This is a problem from coursera.org course "Python for Everybody" where I have to find and print the e-mail id with most number of mail sent from a text named "mailbox-short.txt". The problem statement is:

Write a program to read through the mbox-short.txt and figure out who has sent the greatest number of mail messages. The program looks for 'From ' lines and takes the second word of those lines as the person who sent the mail. The program creates a Python dictionary that maps the sender's mail address to a count of the number of times they appear in the file. After the dictionary is produced, the program reads through the dictionary using a maximum loop to find the most prolific committer.

I have tried in the following way:

```
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
count=dict()
for line in handle:
    line=line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith('From'):
        continue
    else: 

        words=line.split()
        mail=words[1]
        count[mail]=count.get(mail,0)+1

x=list(count.values())
y=max(x)
for email, num in count.items():
    if num ==y:
        email_id=email

print(email_id,y)
```

Now the error is everytime I run this code, it runs swiftly but the result becomes double. Like, the expected result is

```
 cwen@iupui.edu 5
```

But I get

```
cwen@iupui.edu 10.
```

I even printed the whole dictionary and saw that number of sent mails by all the mail id's become double.

A similar problem based on the same text was given in the "list" section of the course and it was required to find the sender email ids. In that case also my code gave double result. Such as, the expected result was:

```
cwen@iupui.edu 
cwen@iupui.edu 
cwen@iupui.edu 
cwen@iupui.edu 
cwen@iupui.edu
```

But the actual result was:

```
cwen@iupui.edu 
cwen@iupui.edu 
cwen@iupui.edu 
cwen@iupui.edu 
cwen@iupui.edu 
cwen@iupui.edu 
cwen@iupui.edu 
cwen@iupui.edu 
cwen@iupui.edu 
cwen@iupui.edu
```

I can't understand what's the problem. Can you help me please?

The mentioned file named "mbox-short.txt" can be found here:

```
https://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox-short.txt
```

Comment: Good attempt, I would recommend to take a look at Counter in collections, https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter , that could be a bit nicer approach. And not sure if you are closing file handle later, I would recommend to take a look at 'with open('workfile') as f:' approach as it is safer.

Comment: @Dolfa Thanks for the suggestion!
Actually, the problem puts some restriction about how to write the code and grades  according to that. But I will definitely try according yo your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is doing exactly what you tell it to. It's looking for lines starting with `"From"`. In the file, the first email has 2 lines like this:

`From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008`
and then later on in the same email:
`From: stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za`.

Your code is counting both of these lines. according to the problem spec, you should be looking for `"From "` - e.g. From followed by a space.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't even notice that. That was a good learning. :)